# What are the possible repurcussions of unplugging an eGPU without ‘ejecting’ it?

Tags: macos, gpu, pci-express, thunderbolt, enclosures

So, at least on macOS, your computer may complain when you simply *unplug* a Thunderbolt / PCIe GPU:

[image: macOS error message when eGPU unplugged: GPU not disconnected properly]

I've basically been ignoring this, so far — when my computer is asleep, it takes a *substantial* time for it to wake up, and all my displays to turn on and become responsive. When it's time to leave the house, I don't really want to sit down at the computer, wake it up, attach my smartcard, log in, and select ‘eject eGPU.’

So: What downsides are there, to simply unplugging a PCIe (via Thunderbolt) GPU from a laptop? Especially any specific to Macs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure GPU drivers run in kernel space, so I imagine a kernel panic (full system crash requiring reboot) is a possibility.

Comment: Hardware-wise you should be safe as the port is hot pluggable, but you should always follow the proper procedure